# Restructure time series from list(list()) datasets

Tags: r

Datasets = https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NngK_WAgSfNb6D0m_Wdke_fghvSL2suL/view?usp=share_link

```
test1 <- download(projectURL = db_url, fileName = "data")
> #####
> N1 <- test1$N1
> N1$`2023`$`11`$`16`$`19:24:00`
[1] "26.8;89;0.5;548;0.030;0.02;0.13;3;22;27;30;3.56" # "T", "RH", "CO", "CO2", "CH2O", "O3", "NO2", "VOC", "PM1", "PM2.5", "PM10", "Battery"
```

I wanna create a data frame, and it looks like this :

```
Date       |Hour      | T   | RH |...
---------------------------------------
2023-11-16 | 19:24:00 | 26.8| 89 | ...
2023-11-16 | 19:34:00 | 27.8| 90 | ...
2023-11-16 | 19:44:00 | 28.8| 91 | ...
```

Comment: This kind of problem is highly dependent on the _exact_ structure of the object, which you haven't given us. Are you able to provide a link to the data set?

Comment: Thank you very much. Here it is : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NngK_WAgSfNb6D0m_Wdke_fghvSL2suL/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1):

You can `unlist` the result, then use `read.csv` using a semicolon separator for the columns. The date-times can be parsed from the unlisted names too:

```r
N1 <- cbind(Time = as.POSIXct(names(unlist(test1$data$N1)), 
                        format = '%Y.%m.%d.%H:%M:%S'),
      read.csv(text = unname(unlist(test1$data$N1)), 
               header = FALSE, sep = ';') |>
        setNames(c("T", "RH", "CO", "CO2", "CH2O", "O3", "NO2", 
                   "VOC", "PM1", "PM2.5", "PM10", "Battery")))
```

This results in:

```r
N1
#>                   Time    T RH  CO CO2  CH2O   O3  NO2 VOC PM1 PM2.5 PM10 Battery
#> 1  2023-10-01 00:08:24 27.9 83 0.5 428 0.023 0.03 0.01   0  91   113  123    3.89
#> 2  2023-10-01 00:18:37 27.8 83 0.5 427 0.021 0.02 0.01   0  96   117  127    3.89
#> 3  2023-10-01 00:28:49 27.7 82 0.5 428 0.021 0.02 0.01   0  87   108  121    3.94
#> 4  2023-10-01 00:39:02 27.6 82 0.5 430 0.018 0.02 0.01   0  85   105  118    3.86
#> 5  2023-10-01 00:49:14 27.4 82 0.5 430 0.018 0.04 0.01   0  87   108  121    3.90
#> 6  2023-10-01 00:59:26 27.3 82 0.5 424 0.017 0.03 0.01   0  89   109  121    3.86
#> 7  2023-10-01 01:09:39 27.1 81 0.5 410 0.017 0.02 0.04   0  75    93  105    3.83
#> 8  2023-10-01 01:19:51 26.8 81 0.5 407 0.016 0.02 0.09   0  60    74   84    3.84
#> 9  2023-10-01 01:30:04 26.6 81 0.5 406 0.016 0.02 0.16   0  53    65   73    3.86
#> 10 2023-10-01 01:40:17 26.4 81 0.5 405 0.016 0.02 0.18   0  48    60   67    3.84
#> 11 2023-10-01 01:50:29 26.3 81 0.5 405 0.016 0.02 0.17   0  48    60   67    3.89
#> 12 2023-10-01 02:00:42 26.1 82 0.5 405 0.015 0.02 0.28   0  48    60   67    3.89
#> 13 2023-10-01 02:10:56 26.0 82 0.5 405 0.015 0.02 0.26   0  48    58   66    3.85
#> 14 2023-10-01 02:21:09 25.7 83 0.5 404 0.015 0.02 0.29   0  48    60   67    3.86
#> 15 2023-10-01 02:31:20 25.6 83 0.5 405 0.015 0.02 0.28   0  53    66   74    3.84
#> 16 2023-10-01 02:41:33 25.5 83 0.5 405 0.015 0.02 0.33   0  50    62   69    3.86
#> 17 2023-10-01 02:51:46 25.6 83 0.5 405 0.015 0.02 0.31   0  52    63   72    3.86
#> 18 2023-10-01 03:01:59 25.4 83 0.5 405 0.015 0.02 0.35   0  50    62   69    3.80
#> 19 2023-10-01 03:12:11 25.5 83 0.5 404 0.015 0.02 0.33   0  55    68   76    3.81
#> 20 2023-10-01 03:22:24 25.5 83 0.5 405 0.015 0.02 0.23   0  53    66   74    3.82
#> 21 2023-10-01 03:32:37 25.5 82 0.5 405 0.016 0.02 0.24   0  56    69   78    3.76
#> 22 2023-10-01 03:42:49 25.6 81 0.5 404 0.016 0.02 0.28   0  58    73   82    3.76
#> 23 2023-10-01 03:53:02 25.7 81 0.5 405 0.016 0.02 0.13   0  60    74   84    3.76
#> 24 2023-10-01 04:03:14 25.7 81 0.5 406 0.016 0.02 0.06   0  66    81   92    3.84
#> 25 2023-10-01 04:13:26 25.8 81 0.5 406 0.017 0.02 0.01   0  57    70   79    3.80
#> 26 2023-10-01 04:23:39 25.9 81 0.5 406 0.017 0.02 0.01   0  59    73   83    3.82
#> 27 2023-10-01 04:33:52 25.8 80 0.5 405 0.017 0.02 0.01   0  54    67   75    3.75
#> 28 2023-10-01 04:44:04 25.9 80 0.5 406 0.017 0.02 0.01   0  62    76   86    3.76
#> 29 2023-10-01 04:54:17 25.9 80 0.5 406 0.018 0.02 0.03   0  63    79   90    3.76
#> 30 2023-10-01 05:04:29 25.8 80 0.5 406 0.016 0.02 0.22   0  68    84   94    3.78
#> 31 2023-10-01 05:14:41 25.8 80 0.5 405 0.017 0.02 0.15   0  65    80   91    3.75
#> 32 2023-10-01 05:24:54 25.8 80 0.5 405 0.016 0.02 0.26   0  69    85   96    3.74
#> 33 2023-10-01 05:35:07 25.7 81 0.5 405 0.017 0.02 0.06   0  62    76   86    3.76
#> 34 2023-10-01 05:45:20 25.7 81 0.5 405 0.017 0.02 0.12   0  54    67   75    3.78
#> 35 2023-10-01 05:55:33 25.6 80 0.5 405 0.016 0.02 0.39   0  73    90  102    3.73
#> 36 2023-10-01 06:08:58 26.5 77 0.5 400 0.016 0.02 0.33   0  74    92  104    3.74
#> 37 2023-10-01 06:19:04 26.2 78 0.5 404 0.017 0.02 0.23   0  69    85   96    3.70
#> 38 2023-10-01 06:29:17 26.3 78 0.5 404 0.017 0.02 0.29   0  78    96  108    3.76
#> 39 2023-10-01 06:39:29 26.6 78 0.5 404 0.017 0.02 0.09   0  64    80   90    3.76
#> 40 2023-10-01 06:49:42 27.1 76 0.5 403 0.017 0.02 0.43   0  78    96  108    3.73
#> 41 2023-10-01 06:59:56 27.7 74 0.5 400 0.017 0.02 0.50   0  69    85   96    3.75
#> 42 2023-10-01 07:10:09 28.6 72 0.5 400 0.017 0.02 0.29   0  69    86   98    3.76
#> 43 2023-10-01 07:20:22 29.6 69 0.5 402 0.017 0.02 0.32   0  78    96  108    3.78
#> 44 2023-10-01 07:30:35 30.9 67 0.5 400 0.017 0.00 0.40   0  66    81   92    3.69
#> 45 2023-10-01 07:40:50 32.4 65 0.5 402 0.018 0.00 0.19   0  76    94  106    3.76
#> 46 2023-10-01 07:51:03 33.1 64 0.5 402 0.022 0.00 0.01   0  75    93  105    3.77
#> 47 2023-10-01 08:01:15 34.1 62 0.5 400 0.026 0.00 0.01   0  87   108  121    3.74
#> 48 2023-10-01 08:11:30 34.5 60 0.5 402 0.022 0.00 0.01   0  94   115  124    3.79
#> 49 2023-10-01 08:21:43 35.7 59 0.5 403 0.028 0.00 0.01   0  84   103  116    3.75
#> 50 2023-10-01 08:31:55 37.4 57 0.5 403 0.030 0.00 0.01   0  86   107  120    3.79
#> 51 2023-10-01 08:42:08 37.0 57 0.5 402 0.028 0.00 0.01   0  85   104  117    3.83
#> 52 2023-10-01 08:52:20 37.3 56 0.5 403 0.032 0.00 0.01   0  84   103  117    3.77
#> 53 2023-10-01 09:02:33 38.8 53 0.5 405 0.032 0.00 0.28   0  91   112  123    3.85
#> 54 2023-10-01 09:12:46 39.7 53 0.5 407 0.037 0.00 0.01   0  80    99  112    3.79
#> 55 2023-10-01 09:22:59 39.8 52 0.5 414 0.041 0.00 0.01   0  92   114  124    3.85
#> 56 2023-10-01 09:33:11 40.7 50 0.5 419 0.035 0.00 0.01   0  90   110  122    3.84
#> 57 2023-10-01 09:43:23 40.6 50 0.5 414 0.035 0.00 0.01   0  93   115  124    3.84
#> 58 2023-10-01 09:53:38 42.0 49 0.5 435 0.037 0.00 0.01   0  77    95  107    3.85
#> 59 2023-10-01 10:03:51 42.3 49 0.5 422 0.047 0.00 0.01   0  74    91  103    3.87
#> 60 2023-10-01 10:14:04 43.1 47 0.5 427 0.050 0.00 0.01   0  81   100  114    3.91
#> 61 2023-10-01 10:24:16 43.5 46 0.5 414 0.038 0.00 0.01   0  79    98  111    3.91
#> 62 2023-10-01 10:34:28 42.9 46 0.5 408 0.048 0.00 0.01   0  79    98  111    3.91
#> 63 2023-10-01 10:44:39 41.9 47 0.5 407 0.042 0.02 0.01   0  81   100  114    3.92
#> 64 2023-10-01 10:54:51 41.2 48 0.5 407 0.041 0.02 0.01   0  78    96  108    3.85
#> 65 2023-10-01 11:05:03 40.2 49 0.5 406 0.032 0.02 0.42   0  90   111  122    3.87
#> 66 2023-10-01 11:15:14 38.7 51 0.5 403 0.033 0.02 0.01   0  84   103  116    3.84
#> 67 2023-10-01 11:25:26 36.9 53 0.5 402 0.027 0.02 0.01   0  86   106  120    3.86
#> 68 2023-10-01 11:35:38 36.4 53 0.5 400 0.018 0.06 3.86   0  86   106  120    3.89
#> 69 2023-10-01 11:45:51 36.8 52 0.5 403 0.018 0.02 0.07   0  76    94  106    3.84
#> 70 2023-10-01 11:56:03 36.8 52 0.5 401 0.017 0.02 0.01   0  73    90  102    3.86
#> 71 2023-10-01 12:06:15 37.1 52 0.5 402 0.023 0.02 0.01   0  68    84   95    3.84
#> 72 2023-10-01 12:16:27 37.0 52 0.5 400 0.025 0.02 0.01   0  72    88   99    3.89
#> 73 2023-10-01 12:26:40 37.2 52 0.5 400 0.033 0.02 0.01   0  62    77   86    3.85
#> 74 2023-10-01 12:36:51 37.2 52 0.5 402 0.033 0.02 0.01   0  73    90  102    3.86
#> 75 2023-10-01 12:47:03 36.5 52 0.5 402 0.026 0.02 0.01   0  78    96  108    3.88
#> 76 2023-10-01 12:57:15 36.0 52 0.5 401 0.017 0.02 0.35   0  74    91  103    3.81
#>  [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 919 rows ]
```